# MySQL: Get all combinations

Tags: mysql, join, select, cross-join, nullif

given I have a user table *users*:

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Adam |
| 3 | Charlie |

Now I want to get all combinations of one or two users:

| user1 | user2 |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | NULL |
| Bob | Adam |
| Bob | Charlie |
| Adam | NULL |
| Adam | Bob |
| Adam | Charlie |
| Charlie | NULL |
| Charlie | Bob |
| Charlie | Adam |

Assuming I want to get only two-person combinations, I would be simply able to do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM users u1 
LEFT JOIN users u2 on u1.id!=u2.id
```

However, I want to include combinations with only one users. How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a self `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT u1.name AS user1,
       NULLIF(u2.name, u1.name) AS user2
FROM users u1 CROSS JOIN users u2
ORDER BY u1.user_id, NULLIF(u2.user_id, u1.user_id);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/THEd2RDo).